# Angular Lazy Loading no me funciona

Tags: javascript, angular

Este es mi app-rounting.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './components/form/form.module#FormModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Y este es el Form Module que se carga en el app-rounting.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsRoutingModule } from '../form/forms-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class FormsModule { }
```

Y este es mi Form Routing donde estan las rutas que se llaman del Form Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DatosComponent } from './datos/datos.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'datos',
    component: DatosComponent
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class FormsRoutingModule { }
```

Pero cuando cargo mi formulario en el navegador en la consola me aparece este error y no me carga el componente

**Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './components/form/form.module'
Error: Cannot find module './components/form/form.module'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es probar en tu archivo **app-rounting.module** cargar las rutas de esta forma:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full },
    { path: 'form', loadChildren: './components/form/form.module#FormModule'},
];
```

Como otra opción si estas usando **angular 9** puedes usar esta otra forma:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full },
   { path: 'form', loadChildren: () => import('./components/form/form.module').then(m => m.FormModule),},

];
```

Espero te ayude

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: ya corregi las ultimas lineas, en loadChildren

Comment: aunque mejor es que pares tu proyecto y lo vuelvas a ejecutar

Comment: Si efectivamente coloque la opcion de angular 9 y funciono

Comment: Genial me alegra haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un typo en la ruta te falta "s" en `FormModule` porque el módulo se llama `FormsModule`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './components/form/form.module#FormsModule' },
];
```